# Leftnav shrinks width when set to position "fixed"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, flexbox

I have a main content area and sidebar, created with a combination of Bootstrap and Flexbox.

[image]

I want to fix the navbar from scrolling with the page, but if I apply `position: fixed` it no longer fills it's horizontal` space...

[image]

why is this, and how can I remedy this?

[The codepen is here.](http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/qbXvOw)

**UPDATE**

The chosen answer does work on the codepen, but in the real site it only works when then window is smaller, like iPad-portrait-size:
[image]

at a normal desktop width, the leftnav keeps getting larger...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do `position: fixed;` on a *top-level* element that is also part of a `display:flex;` layout. But if you get a little clever, you can use `position:fixed;` on a *child* element.

You'll have to ditch the Bootstrap grid though - it's using percentages and margins that aren't compatible with flexbox. [See my Codepen fork of your work](http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/XXaGEG).

HTML:

```
  <div class="two-col-wrapper">
    <div class="leftnav">
      <div class="list-group list-group-fixed">
        <a class="list-group-item active" href="">Validate Address</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="">Get Postal Codes</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="">Get City/State/Province</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="">Get Candidate Address</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="">Auto Complete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nobis, accusamus delectus amet cupiditate expedita ex ducimus fugiat voluptatibus.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.two-col-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  .main-content {
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 90px 25px;
    flex-grow: 1;
   }

  .leftnav {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 90px 10px;
    flex: 2 0 200px;

    .list-group-fixed {
      position: fixed;
    }
  }
}
```

But remember, you got clever so there is a drawback -[per the W3C rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items):

> An absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout.

Comment: but the list group is not a child of the flex container... only the two gray divs are,

Comment: It doesn't matter. When using `display:flex;` it assumes it is controlling the viewport completely. There are ways to do what you trying to do wth flexbox though, I'll think about that layout a bit more.

Comment: Please see edits to my original question.  The code you posted works fine in the pen, but in the actual page the left nav grows in width to stay attached to the main content instead of stopping at 200px...

Comment: You have to define some width on the parent element for the fixed child to work correctly (hence the `flex: 2 0 200px;`). You could dynamically insert that value with some simple JS though.

Answer (score 0):

you can add flex-shrink to reduce that space. Add to .leftnav {}

```
  flex-shrink: 7;
```

Here's the forked version of your pen: http://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/wMqOmr